# Exception when trying to use JDBC to BigQuery template when using Google's Dataflow

Tags: java, jdbc, salesforce, google-cloud-dataflow

I'm trying to use Google's Dataflow using the JDBC to `BigQuery` template to extract information from `Salesforce` into `BigQuery`. The JDBC Driver I am using is [Progress' DataDirect JDBC Driver for Salesforce](https://www.progress.com/jdbc/salesforce).

I've confirmed that I can connect to Salesforce using the driver locally.

Unfortunately when I create a Job within Dataflow using the driver I get the following exception:

> java.lang.RuntimeException: org.apache.beam.sdk.util.UserCodeException: java.sql.SQLException: Cannot get a connection, pool error Unable to activate object

I can provide a stack trace if necessary.

I've configured the template as follows (where values within <> are set appropriately):

```
Regional endpoint: us-central1
JDBC connection URL string: jdbc:datadirect:sforce://path.to.salesforce.com;SecurityToken=<Security Token>;User=<User>;Password=<Password>
JDBC driver class name: com.ddtek.jdbc.sforce.SForceDriver
JDBC source SQL query: SELECT Email FROM LEAD;
BigQuery output table: <project>:<dataset>.<table_name>
GCS paths for JDBC drivers: gs://<some_bucket>/sforce.jar
Temporary directory for BigQuery loading process: gs://<some_bucket>/staging
Temporary location: gs://<some_bucket>/tmp
```

I'm hoping that someone familiar with this use case will be able to help me determine why I'm getting this exception and how I can go about resolving it. My working assumptions are that I'm using the driver incorrectly, I need to add additional drivers to GCS, or there is an issue connecting to Salesforce through Dataflow.

Edit:

The JDBC driver from Progress that I am using is version 6.0. I'm unsure which version of the Dataflow SDK is being used when I use the UI but when I have tried working with the Google Dataflow SDK locally it looks like I'm using version 2.5.0 based on the pom.xml.

Comment: Hi, please provide your JDBC Salesforce Driver version and Dataflow SDK version.

Comment: Hey Gonzalo, the JDBC Salesforce Driver version is 6.0. I'm attempting to use Dataflow's web console to connect so I'm unsure what version of its SDK. However, when I was working with the JDBC driver locally (where I also was having an issue but not when testing connection) I was using version 2.5.0 of the Dataflow SDK (based on the generated pom.xml).

Answer (score 0):

I didn't find any relevant issue between the JDBC and Dataflow versions, so I will suggest to take a look on the following tutorials from Progress website to understand if you are using the driver correctly:

1. [Setting Google Cloud Dataflow SDK](https://www.progress.com/tutorials/jdbc/import-salesforce-data-in-to-google-bigquery-using-google-cloud-dataflow#setting-up-google-cloud-data-flow-sdk-and-project)
2. [Import data from Salesforce into Google Bigquery using Dataflow](https://www.progress.com/tutorials/jdbc/import-salesforce-data-in-to-google-bigquery-using-google-cloud-dataflow)

and if the exception persist, please create an issue with GCP following this [guide](https://developers.google.com/issue-tracker/guides/create-issue-ui)

Comment: Thanks for the links, Isaac. I've been through both of those Progress pages quite a few times. I appreciate the link to the creating an issue documentation.